# Where is the Grails SDK located when installed using homebrew?

Tags: intellij-idea, homebrew

I installed grails using homebrew, and I know that the files are installed in /usr/local/Cellar/grails.  I'd like to reference that grails installation as a Grails SDK location in my IDE (e.g. IntelliJ), but what directory should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Grails version 2.2.4 as an example, the correct SDK path is:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/grails/2.2.4/libexec
```

It's not `/usr/local/Cellar/grails/2.2.4` as you might normally think.